# Custom home page in SharePoint 2010 with web parts

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, page-layout, layouts

How to create a custom layout for the sharepoint home page? Right now, I need a home page with 2 rows. One with three columns and one with 4 columns.

I looked all over the internet but couldn't find an example for create a layout for the sharepoint home page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a couple of things here:

1) Using SharePoint Designer to edit the default.aspx page and add some web part zones, etc.

2) Create a Pages library that lets you create pages with various different layouts.  Then set one of those pages as your sites home page.